# Find an equation belonging to the same coaxal system

Tags: geometry, circles

Prove that in general there are two circles of non-intersecting coaxal system touching a given straight line. Find the equation of the two circles belonging to the same coaxal system as $$ x^2+y^2+8y+8=0$$ and $$ x^2+y^2+8x+16y+4=0 $$ which touch the line $x=2$.

Comment: You may want to read the Wikipedia [Apollonian circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles) page.

Comment: Very helpful but only to add knowledge.

Comment: Bare problem statements are generally ill-received here and your question will likely be closed without some more context or your own attempts at solving it. See [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What are you allowed to use? This is quite straightforward if you use dual conics.